# macOS Sonoma symlink - "Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

I'm trying to set up a symlink for neovim config that I store in a git repo. It works fine when running on Linux, but when I try on my macbook I get the following error:

```
ln -sfn ~/dotfiles-and-utils/nvim ~/.config
ln: /Users/<my username>/.config/nvim: Operation not permitted
```

My guess from looking for a solution to this is that it has something to do with macOS SIP, but at the same time I don't think `/Users/username/.config` should be covered by SIP?

Comment: This means usually that you don't have the necessary permissions for such a symlink. Try it with `sudo`.

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo` doesn't fix the problem. The other thing is that it allows me to do a symlink to `~/.zshrc` without `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was because there was already a `nvim` directory where I was trying to put the symlink. I was under the impression that the `-sfn` flags would take care of replacing anything pre-existing but apparently not

Comment: Check as answered two days later...